# Could not convert Rows to Columns in gridview in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is the code I worked to convert Rows to Columns. The problem is I got the expected output when I keep Checkpoint in code but not in browser screen. I bind the output datatable to a gridview where the datasource is right but no proper result in output screen??

```
     DataTable outputTable = new DataTable();

    // Add columns by looping rows

    // Header row's first column is same as in inputTable
    outputTable.Columns.Add(inputTable.Columns[0].ColumnName.ToString());

    // Header row's second column onwards, 'inputTable's first column taken
    foreach (DataRow inRow in inputTable.Rows)
    {
        string newColName = inRow[0].ToString();
        outputTable.Columns.Add(newColName);
    }

    // Add rows by looping columns        
    for (int rCount = 1; rCount <= inputTable.Columns.Count -1; rCount++)
    {
        DataRow newRow = outputTable.NewRow();

        // First column is inputTable's Header row's second column
        newRow[0] = inputTable.Columns[rCount].ColumnName.ToString();
        for (int cCount = 0; cCount <= inputTable.Rows.Count - 1; cCount++)
        {
            string colValue = inputTable.Rows[cCount][rCount].ToString();
            newRow[cCount + 1] = colValue;
        }
        outputTable.Rows.Add(newRow);

    }
    return outputTable;
```

Comment: Why are you not doing it at db end?
Use pivot table to get data, rows into columns.

Comment: actually when the page loads, I loaded the gridview with headertext with Textboxes (row-wise). I need to convert the rows to columns. The above got converted but doesn't reflect in webpage ....

Comment: No DB is involved during page load in this ... Just design

Comment: Why do you need to do that?

Comment: As you said you can see outputTable has right values during debugging, then there would be some issue during binding. Can you show the binding code as well?

Comment: @HaseebAsif     DataTable dtnew=ConvertToColumns(dt);
                gvlistmonoprix.DataSource = dtnew;
                gvlistmonoprix.DataBind();

Comment: your **outputTable** has the data as per requirements? Then how data is being displayed in the grid, Is it appearing column wise instead of row wise?

Comment: I do not know how it is displaying.. The gridview is same and adds 8 rows additionally(browser page).

Comment: If **outputTable** has proper data, then your aspx (grid view declaration could have some problem). Can I see that?

Comment: <asp:GridView ID="gvlistmonoprix" runat="server" ShowFooter="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Width="640px"><Columns><asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Combo">ItemTemplate>asp:DropDownList ID="combolist1" runat="server" Height="22px" Width="111px" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList></ItemTemplate></asp:TemplateField><asp:TemplateField HeaderText="50"><ItemTemplate><asp:TextBox ID="size50"Width="50px"runat="server"OnTextChanged="calculatetotal_textchangedVillerValla"></asp:TextBox>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I have used your code and it's working fine

```
<asp:GridView ID="testGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="true" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
```

and Code behind with sample data is as follows

```
    private DataTable createSampleDataTable()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        //Creating Columns
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ID",typeof(int)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name",typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("DOB", typeof(DateTime)));

        //Creating Sample Rows
        DataRow dr;
        for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
        {
            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["ID"] = i;
            dr["Name"] = String.Format("Name {0}",i);
            dr["DOB"] = new DateTime(2014, i, i);
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }

        return dt;
    }

    public void BindTestGrid()
    {
        DataTable inputTable = createSampleDataTable();
        DataTable outputTable = new DataTable();

        // Add columns by looping rows

        // Header row's first column is same as in inputTable
        outputTable.Columns.Add(inputTable.Columns[0].ColumnName.ToString());

        // Header row's second column onwards, 'inputTable's first column taken
        foreach (DataRow inRow in inputTable.Rows)
        {
            string newColName = inRow[0].ToString();
            outputTable.Columns.Add(newColName);
        }

        // Add rows by looping columns        
        for (int rCount = 1; rCount <= inputTable.Columns.Count - 1; rCount++)
        {
            DataRow newRow = outputTable.NewRow();

            // First column is inputTable's Header row's second column
            newRow[0] = inputTable.Columns[rCount].ColumnName.ToString();
            for (int cCount = 0; cCount <= inputTable.Rows.Count - 1; cCount++)
            {
                string colValue = inputTable.Rows[cCount][rCount].ToString();
                newRow[cCount + 1] = colValue;
            }
            outputTable.Rows.Add(newRow);

            testGrid.DataSource = outputTable;
            testGrid.DataBind();
        }            
    }
```

I have Added the grid view markup as given by you and it is also showing two rows which is desired. As there are three rows in the dataTable, Ist rows is header row and other two rows are data rows.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvlistmonoprix" runat="server" ShowFooter="True"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Width="640px">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Combo">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="combolist1" runat="server" Height="22px" Width="111px" AutoPostBack="true">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="50">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="size50" Width="50px" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: The above code gets converted. I need a textbox instead of passing the string values and added to the row??? How to post the screenshot here ??

Comment: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2vj761v&s=8#.U3C3xIGSydg.....Click on the link to see the output What I've got???